# ReactJS - Can't type on input fields

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm having an issue with the typing on input fields.. i'm working on a big project, which already had other input fields, which were working at the time i wrote them.. today i was adding new fields and noticed that the old fields didn't accept any kind of input.

I know this a common question, but my problem is neither not having the value or the onChange set.

Here is a example of the new fields i was working on.

```js
<TextField 
    id="outlined-basic" 
    name="text-container-field"
    label="Texto" 
    variant="outlined" 
    value={this.state.customText} 
    onChange={this.onCustomTextChange.bind(this)}
/>

<input 
    type="text" 
    name="text-container" 
    value={this.state.customText} 
    onChange={this.onCustomTextChange.bind(this)} 
/>
```

And the onChange function

```js
onCustomTextChange = event => {
    this.setState({customText: event.target.value})
}
```

i wrote the input fields with both MUI and native input just to check if there was an issue with MUI TextField, but it's all the same.

Comment: ya because you are using same state var for 2 inputs. Use different keys eg(`customText1` for textarea & `customText2` input)

Comment: @bogdanoff thank you for answering.. but it doesn't seem to be the problem.. i think something in another compnent is disabling the input